# How to cast []string with variable number of items?

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse log strings, where fields are glued with "|" char. All logs suppose to have 20 fields, but some logs have less. I don't want to discard them, but rather fill `Log{}` with whatever info was there in the log string.

```
type Log struct {
     Field1  string
     Field2  uint64
     Field3  string
     // ...
     Field20 string
}
```

Knowing that it's not possible to check if index exists within a slice, this looks suboptimal:

```
log := Log{}
c := len(fields)

if c > 0 {
    log.Field1 = fields[0]
}

if c > 1 {
    log.Field2, _ = strconv.ParseUint(fields[1], 0, 64)
}

if c > 3 {
    log.Field3 = fields[2]
}

//...
```

Any better ways doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider a range loop with a switch on index inside?

Comment: @mkopriva since i'm completely knew to golang, I'm not quite sure how to do that. Range loop presumes that proper field is going to be pointed to respective index, which, again, I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: This https://play.golang.org/p/tsh1cNxs3R is what i had in mind. But Cerise Limon's answer seems to be a more optimal option.

Comment: Note that Go doesn't support type casting; only time conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use [switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) with [fallthrough](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements):

```
switch len(fields) {
case 20:
    log.Field20 = something(fields[19])
    fallthrough

// ...

case 3:
   log.Field3 = fields[2]
   fallthrough
case 2:
    log.Field2, _ = strconv.ParseUint(fields[1], 0, 64)
    fallthrough
case 1:
    log.Field1 = fields[0]
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/szYPmSIPrK) (thank you @mkopriva for starting example)

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed smart and interesting. I was struggling what answer to accept. However, I liked `copy` just a little bit over your suggestion as it requires less code to write. In any case, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to simply ensure that you always have 20 elements in your slice. Assuming you're populating `fields` with `strings.Split`, for example:

```
fields := make([]string, 20)
copy(fields, strings.Split(input, ","))

// Now `fields` has 20 elements, the first N of which are populated
// by your input, the remainder of which are empty strings (""), so
// you can easily set your struct fields now.

log := Log{
    Field1:  fields[0],
    Field2:  fields[1],
    // ...
    Field20: fields[19],
}
```